# "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

when I make post request via `XMLHttpRequest` it work very well but, when I make a get request in the django API view `http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/` and I write a new text in the text box I got an error `"detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`
here are my files code.
`serlizers.py`
the app is just like tweet app where I'm following [this course](https://youtu.be/f1R_bykXHGE)
[myRepo](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Tweetme-2/issues/6)

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Tweet


class TweetActionsSerlizer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    action = serializers.CharField()
    content = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)

    def validate_action(self, value):
        # lower = lower case letter.
        # strip = drop spaces for example "like ".strip() = "like"
        value = value.lower().strip()
        if not value in ['like', 'unlike', 'retweet']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("this is not avalid action")
        return value


class CreateTweeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ['id', 'content', 'like']

    # def get_likes(self, obj):
        # return obj.like.count()
        # this convert the array of users ids wholiekd to the number of likes

    def validate_content(self, value):
        if len(value) > 200:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This Tweet is too long")
        return value


class TweeSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # like = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # if the is no is_retweet @property function in models  you will nedd this line.
    # is_retweet = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # content = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    # this will retrun the data of parents.
    # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/ parent:{id,content,like}
    parent = CreateTweeSerializers(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ['user', 'id', 'content', 'like',
                  'is_retweet', 'parent', ]  # 'timestamp']

    # def get_content(self, obj):
    #     content = obj.content
    #     # if th it is a retweet then its content will = the content of the parent.
    #     # this is to make sure that the already existed tweets will have the content of their parents.
    #     if obj.is_retweet:
    #         content = obj.parent.content
    #     return content
```

`settings.py`

### the setting mostly the default settings but at the end I added the restframework settings.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6)ej64kx92vba7!6tq76^k0smwy)$t5z1m$q6@tn0gxvd58cl9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'social',
    'rest_framework'


]
SITE_ID = 1


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'vertualizor.urls'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'mydomain.com']

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vertualizor.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of allauth
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # allauth specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES = [
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
]

if DEBUG:
    DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES += [
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
}
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Tweet
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url
from .serializers import CreateTweeSerializers, TweeSerializers, TweetActionsSerlizer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
# this woll make POST request work and re-render the new posts.


@api_view(["POST"])
# @authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication,MyCustomAuth])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_create_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = CreateTweeSerializers(data=request.POST)
    # raise_exception= if form.error reutnr error and status400
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(user=request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response({}, status=400)


def home_view(request, *args, **kwards):
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', context={}, status=200)


@api_view(["GET"])
def post_view(request, postId, *args, **kwards):
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(id=postId)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({}, status=404)
    return Response(TweeSerializers(qs.first()).data, status=200)


@api_view(["DELETE", 'POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_delete_view(request, postId, *args, **kwards):
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(id=postId)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({}, status=404)
    qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({"message": 'you cant delete this Post'}, status=401)
    obj = qs.first()
    obj.delete()
    return Response({'Message': "post removed"}, status=200)


@api_view(["GET"])
def posts_list_view(request, *args, **kwards):
    qs = Tweet.objects.all()
    serializer = TweeSerializers(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post_actions_view(request, *args, **kwards):
    '''
    actions = like,unlike,retweet
    '''
    # i dont understand how request.POST will send the id and the action type to the serlizer?
    # data=request.POST was a mistake
    serlizer = TweetActionsSerlizer(data=request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if serlizer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        data = serlizer.validated_data
        post_id = data.get('id')
        action = data.get('action')
        # you must serlize data to the get them.
        content = data.get('content')
    qs = Tweet.objects.filter(id=post_id)
    if not qs.exists():
        return Response({}, status=404)
    obj = qs.first()
    if action == 'like':
        obj.like.add(request.user)
        return Response(serlizer.data, status=200)
    elif action == 'unlike':
        obj.like.remove(request.user)
    elif action == 'retweet':
        newTwee = Tweet.objects.create(
            user=request.user, parent=obj, content=content)
        serlizer = TweeSerializers(newTwee)
        return Response(serlizer.data, status=201)

    return Response({}, status=200)
```

Comment: So shouldn't you send a *POST* request to the `/create`? If it's intended to _create_ something, it needs data, right? Why you're using GET? You probably need a GET request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/` (or however you named it in `urls.py`)

Comment: I'm using get to GET data it has nothing to to with POST, i just included in my code because i don't know if it matter.

Comment: Hmm seems like nice course thank you for the link  Since it is project for educational purposes - do you have a public github repo so it would be easily deploy and debug to help you?

Comment: @madzohan yes good Idea I just pushed my code to github. also I'm using django 3 where the course use django2.2 and I'm using django-allauth where the original course don't , and I made more few changes. [myRepo](https://github.com/aliplutus/Tweet-clone-Tweetme-2/tree/master)

Comment: Bro it is pretty easy but don't give up - complete the course and drf manuals)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was your problem is :)

What I did (leads to "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" msg on your screen) or you can repeat the same via curl or Postman:

1. authenticated as superuser then opened a browser on http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
2. typed "somestring" in Content textarea
3. clicked Post btn (with selected mediatype json)

Ok why is it wrong? - In view request.data have parsed like `{"somestring"}` but it should looks like `{"content":  "somestring"}`

So how it is correct (here I've used token authentication https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)

Request

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token e6f2fdd681d0b023a73cb06e9720867adeb96daf

{"content":  "a"}
```

Response

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "content": "a",
  "like": []
}

Response code: 201 (Created); Time: 50ms; Content length: 33 bytes
```